# Upgrading Angular 8 to Angular 9 Error: .ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular8, angular9

I recently upgraded out Angular 8 application, to Angular 9, using the following commands:

```
ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

The only package that manually needed changes, was `ngx-store` to `ngx-store-9`, which I did with the following commands:

```
npm uninstall ngx-store
npm install ngx-store-9
```

I then went ahead and changed all of the import statements for `ngx-store` to `ngx-store-9`.

I am now receiving the following error when I build my app:

> ERROR in ./src/app/models/companySearchCriteria.ts
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
>   Error: D:_lieben\DevOps\Gtrack Web v3\GTrack.UI\Gtrack\src\app\models\companySearchCriteria.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
>       at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:_lieben\DevOps\Gtrack Web v3\GTrack.UI\Gtrack\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:933:23)
>       at D:_lieben\DevOps\Gtrack Web v3\GTrack.UI\Gtrack\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:41:31
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

Below, is my `tsconfig.app.json` file:

```
      "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I am not quite sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have the same issue. All lazy-loaded modules return message mentioned by OP (warning in my case, not error, though).

Comment: did you come right?  I managed to sort out my problem

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've just created my own thread to not clutter yours. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951542/lazy-loaded-modules-warnings-after-updating-angular-from-8-to-9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, for some reason, the file name in the import statements were capatilized.

For instance, let's say I had the following .ts file: `companySearchModel.ts`

```
export class CompanySearchModel {
    //some properties
}
```

The import statement in another file, where the `companySearchModel` is used, looked like this:

```
import { CompanySearchModel } from './models/CompanySearchModel.ts'
```

When it should have looked, like this:

```
import { CompanySearchModel } from './models/companySearchModel.ts'
```

Not sure why this happened, but after changing the file's name in the import statement to reflect the real name of the file (lower case), it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i only close the compiler and started again.

The problem was resolved.

Hope it works