# Lazy-loaded modules warnings after updating Angular from 8 to 9

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, angular8, angular9

After Angular update all lazy-loaded modules return warning:

```
Error: [path/to/module/module-name.ts] is missing from the TypeScript
compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files'
or 'include' property.
```

My function which returns modules array:

```
export function manifests(prefix = '') {
    return [
        {
            loadChildren: () => import(prefix + '/path/to/a.module').then(m => m.AModule),
            path: 'a',
        },
        {
            loadChildren: () => import(prefix + '/path/to/b.module').then(m => m.BModule),
            path: 'b',
        },
    ]
}
```

If I replace that function with static array everything seems to be fine, though. Why?

My tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts",
    "src/zone-flags.ts",
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
  ]
}
```

Comment: How do you use the `manifests` function?

Comment: Nothing unusual:

`@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    exports: [],
    imports: [DynamicComponentLoaderModule.forRoot(manifests())],
})`

DynamicComponentLoaderModule is our internal module for loading dynamic components. Anyway, it worked that way before Angular migration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for some reason, the file name in the import statements were capatilized.

For instance, let's say I had the following .ts file: `companySearchModel.ts`

```
export class CompanySearchModel {
    //some properties
}
```

The import statement in another file, where the `companySearchModel` is used, looked like this:

```
import { CompanySearchModel } from './models/CompanySearchModel.ts'
```

When it should have looked, like this:

```
import { CompanySearchModel } from './models/companySearchModel.ts'
```

Not sure why this happened, but hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Checked this as well. Nope, that's not the issue in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can add this path to exclude in tsconfig below include property

```
"exclude": [
    "path/to/module"
  ]
```